# Domino FT Search (SSJS) slow on Production server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus, ssjs

I am using SSJS in my Domino based Xpages application and calling FT Search in my Script. The FTSearch results are faster on Development server but slow on Production Server. The data size is same on both Development and Production servers.

What could be the issues, please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are many items you can check:

- Does your production database have a fulltext Index?

  - Settings of the Indexer
  - I/O utilisation of the server (is it busy with something else?)
  - CPU utilisation (potential red Hering: CPU utilisation spikes on insufficient I/O
  - memory. Does the machine swap
  - Antivirus misconfigured (shall not Scan nsf or index files)
  - Someone else’s dB or tasks jam the system

Good hunting!
A good server layout: https://www.wissel.net/blog/2009/04/building-a-high-performance-domino-server.html